# ActiveMQ clean up old queues that seems to just hang around?

Tags: jboss, openshift, activemq-classic, amq

So I have a jboss AMQ 6.3 cluster (3 pods in OpenShift) that keeps growing daily.
Looking in the Java Console, there are a Lot of Queues named clever things like

```
error-user006107e3-85ce-bdf1-f414-34fc448c1eb4
```

which I'm assuming is the reason KahaDB keeps growing in size (currently 120mb each split, up from 100 last week...)
Is there a way to clean these likely dead queues to stop us from running out of memory every 2 weeks?

Edit: Not so sure the error-user is the villain here.. But it does keep growing..

Edit2: Here's the activemq.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
           http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core    
           http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd"> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"    brokerName="${HOSTNAME}" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="10000">
        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
                <policyEntries>
                    <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb" maxBrowsePageSize="700" gcInactiveDestinations="true" inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="30000">

                        <networkBridgeFilterFactory>
                            <conditionalNetworkBridgeFilterFactory replayWhenNoConsumers="true" replayDelay="500" />
                        </networkBridgeFilterFactory>
                    </policyEntry>
                    <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true" gcInactiveDestinations="true" inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="30000">
                        <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                            <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000" />
                        </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    </policyEntry>
                </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false" />
        </managementContext>

        <ioExceptionHandler>
            <defaultIOExceptionHandler ignoreNoSpaceErrors="false"/>
        </ioExceptionHandler>

        <networkConnectors>
            <networkConnector userName="userName" password="password" uri="dns://amq-cluster:61616/?transportType=tcp&amp;queryInterval=30" messageTTL="-1" consumerTTL="1" />
        </networkConnectors>
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb" />
        </persistenceAdapter>

        <plugins>
            <jaasAuthenticationPlugin configuration="activemq" />
        </plugins>
        <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb" />
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb" />
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600&amp;transport.hbGracePeriodMultiplier=2.5" />
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600" />
        </transportConnectors>
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>
    </broker>
    <!-- Do not expose the console or other webapps
    <import resource="jetty.xml" />
    -->
</beans>
```

Comment: Do you have a DLQ or similar? It sounds like messages are being sent to a queue with no consumer to remove them. you would need to provide some config details at minimum and some queue stats.

Comment: @user3788685 Updated question with config.Absolutely. How do I pull queue stats that are relevant?

Comment: have you browsed the queues with jmx or the amq web console to see what they are actually gathering up? that should help narrow it down. What is your producer?

Comment: Digging through a heap dump, there are thousands upon thousands of StoreUsage objects named "default:store:queue://error-user{uuid}:store

Comment: your config does not show the cleanupinterval for KahabDB. Look here https://activemq.apache.org/kahadb

Comment: cleanupInterval is set to 30000 by default. Setting it explicitly did not change anything.